# A stranger smudge on my LCD monitor on gray background

Tags: colors, lcd

I have Dell LCD monitor (and old IPS or eIPS model). Today I have noticed a strange smudge that goes from the top to the bottom on the left side of the monitor appearing only on gray background (you know some programs use gray color scheme). It is not visible on other colors.

And it seems to be most visible in Dracula color scheme in PyCharm (not so much or at all in Photoshop CS6). It also seems that the longer the program is opened the stronger the smudge becomes.

I have been using this monitor on the same spot for years (and only today I switched PyCharm to Dracula color scheme). I pulled the monitor forward and the smudge almost disappeared.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this? Is it a sign to worry?

Comment: A picture might help - is those sort of feathery/fernish looking?

Comment: It looks like an like oily finger smudge or when you have oil in water but in grayscale. I'll see if I can make a picture with a camera.

Comment: There is not distortion of the image whatsoever. It is just as if the screen is dirty. And my first reaction was to clean it. I've just checked the monitor again and it is almost invisible again. I doubt that it will be visible on a picture. It is very strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a guess here, but it sounds like the layers in your monitor have 'split' or delaminated. The oiliness is light getting incorrectly polarised as it passes through a gap between polarized layers. Its unusual but I've had that happen, though that started with a featherlike, grey 'stain'. In the longer run, you may need to consider getting a new monitor.

Comment: It doesn't look like a feather at all. Could it be a magnetic interference?
I tried the built in LCD conditioning function. I couldn't see any signs of that stain but on gray colors and particularly on light gray :) I have no idea if that's a correct way to to it. I made screenshot and sampled to color: RGB: 606365

Comment: On an LCD monitor, can't be magnetic interference

Comment: After a few days I fugured out. Not only this stain is visible on grayish colors (I can see it now on some shades of blue too) but it actually dissappears after the display warms up (BTW it is a really hot summer over here). So it might not be a new "feature".